# How to change Facebook accessToken to sessionKey?

Tags: iphone, facebook, xcode4

IN new Facebook SDK, there is no FBSession, while in my app, I need to use sessionKey. how can I change accessToken to sessionKey?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging into Facebook XMPP with encrypted access token format ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7738616/logging-into-facebook-xmpp-with-encrypted-access-token-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about XMPP login, I just answered this question here: [my accessToken!!(NOT AAA|BBB|CCC any more)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7738616/my-accesstokennot-aaabbbccc-any-more/7739500#7739500)

If you're asking about another method, all other methods should work with the access token in place of the old session key - if not you'll have to clarify what you're doing

Comment: @lgy hi, lgy, thk for your reply. My question is that our app use one third library which need the session key. Previously I got the session key from access token. but now As access token format has changed, i can't get session key any more. is there any way to get it?

Comment: I don't believe so, i think you need to change your library to include the access token in the requests you make to Facebook's servers, all of Facebook's SDKs and (i think) all the popular third party libraries should support this